# Портится качество у изображения при перезапуске приложения

Tags: java, android, picasso

В приложении есть пункт добавления аватара в своем аккаунте, при добавлении его - картинка заливается на сервер и отображается как положено:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkoxa.jpg]

Но если сделать перезапуск приложения, то после этого у изображения теряется качество:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF7hF.jpg]

При сравнении веса и размера изображения между тем что залилось на сервер и оригиналом - все нормально, вес и размер идентичны. Отображение аватара идет напрямую с сервера. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А как у ас картинка отображается? В смысле каким кодом/какой библиотекой? Если это UIL, то попробуйте поиграться с его настройками/сменить на другую либу/свой код. Скорее всего дело в кэшировании однажды загруженного изображения и последующий подгон его под размеры контейнера.

Comment: Кеширование отсутствует, используется Picasso. Код отображения аватарки:
Picasso.with(context).load(link).into(imageview);

Comment: Я с этой либой не работал, но она наверняка умеет кэшировать. Поковыряйте её доки на сей счёт. Наверняка можно как-то настроить кэширование, ибо наверняка таки именно в нём дело. Проверить кэшируется или нет можно попробовав загрузить картинку без сети.

Comment: может быть вина зависит от экрана, у меня разницы нет. Дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос скриншотами примеров.

Comment: Добавил полноценные скриншоты